# Setting multiple SNMP OID values at once as a single action

Tags: snmp

I'd like to be able to configure the component of a software stack through SNMP. I integrated Agent++ into the software, and can already control other values via SNMP. I can detect snmp set operations and refresh the software's state after the configuration value has been updated (for example via snmpset).

However, in some cases, several configuration values are logically grouped together. One example would be a simple network configuration: DHCP yes/no, fixed IP address, netmask, gateway. Exposing each of these values as a separate OID means that every modification will trigger a network reconfiguration, which is not desirable. Instead, I want to first modify the values, and *once I am done*, reconfigure the network adapter.

So, it must be somehow possible to set multiple values over SNMP in one quasi-atomic action, which causes the software to be notified only once for the entire set of modifications.

Is there a possibility for that? There are hacks of course, like packing multiple values in one JSON string and sending that string over SNMP, but I would like to avoid that.